# Error in [.data.frame(counts, , meta$sample) : undefined columns selected Calls: [ -> [.data.frame

Tags: r

I have a meta data frame and a counts data frame. The counts data frame has samples IDs as column headers and has 477 columns. The meta data frame has the first column called samples that has sample IDs as its values in the rows. It has 465 values or rows. I am trying to keep only the samples in the counts file that occur in the samples column of the meta data frame. I have tried this command:

counts=counts[,meta$sample]

however, I get this error

Error in [.data.frame(counts, , meta$sample) :
undefined columns selected
Calls: [ -> [.data.frame

I need help on why I am getting that error when I use that command. I know this works because it worked previously on another data frame and even on a dummy data frame set that I created. So if someone could help explain why this command is not working. Do not require another solution to this just why this command is giving me that error. Appreciate the help

[image: Counts Data Frame]

[image: meta data frame]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that `meta$sample` may be a numeric/integer column and the column names in `counts` is `character`.  When we use `integer` columns, it will be column index i.e. looking for `246264` column instead of the column name `"246264"`.  Convert to `character` and it should work

```
counts[, as.character(meta$sample)]
```

Comment: The values I checked are the same between the both, but still tried your command and am getting another error. I am confused why the original command is not working when it works on my dummy data set and other data frames

Comment: @mikeropri can you try `counts[, trimws(meta$sample)]`

Comment: @mikeropri probably you are trying to subset with character columns i.e. `counts[, as.character(meta$sample)]` if those are the column names instead of index

Comment: I tried both your commands akrun and still getting the original error. The columns are not characters. The meta$sample column is a column of integers. The column headers of counts is numerical sample ids. Appreciate your help guys

Comment: @mikeropri `counts[, intersect(names(counts), as.character(meta$sample))]`.  These are based on the images showed.

Comment: @mikeropri your column header would be numeric values, but its class will be character as column names can't be of type integer

Comment: Yes, akrun, that makes sense. the column headers are a character class while the meta$sample column is integer. I converted the meta$sample column to character class and ran it and it works now. Also, tried the intersect command as you mentioned and it works. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @mikeropri the `intersect` was (just in case where there are some columns not present)

Comment: True, but i had checked that all values in the meta$sample column were in the column header of the counts file. But appreciate that command as well.